# User suspended for posting too many comments....what?

Tags: discussion

I am seeing this account of user [thinking man](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/62907/thinkingman), pretty well known person here I think. Often their questions on probabilities hits HNQ.

The account says "user suspended for posting too many comments".

This is a first to me.

How many comments is too much? and is this real?

Answer (score 4):

It is not "posting too many comments", it is "excessive discussion in comments".

There is a contact form template for this for a reason: the site should be about objectively answerable questions and well-sourced, definite answers. Comments should be about clarifications, not content. Excessive discussions in comments (we need to purge comments and copy them to chat if they're getting too many - and we had to do this for almost every single post of this user) are a sign for users *looking for discussion, not content*.

**That is not what StackExchange is designed for!**

There had been a warning beforehand without a sign of insight. It is pretty much standard procedure and not the first time we do this. There had been year-long suspensions for that already. It's because it disrupts the community and acts as a conductor for ever more people trodding in, discussing and posting content that solicits discussion.

Comment: Philip, Please accept my apologies for an overdue thank you for your handling of this situation.  This is not a philosophy problem. It's identifying a possible pathology. You should be praised, not criticized.

Comment: I was about time someone took care of this users incessant flaming

Comment: Hi Philip, I saw thst the thinkingman account has been updated. The suspension is due to voting irregularities. What is that?

Comment: @IdiosyncraticSoul Use of sockpuppets to vote (and answer) on one's own questions in order to facilitate Hot Network Question probability

Comment: Nice catch. Sorry you have to spend so much time on one person's devious behavior.

Answer (score 3):

A quick glance at thinkingman's stats (provided by your link) points out the problem.

For the 11 months thinkingman has been a member, he has posted 240 questions and 64 answers. Of the 240 questions he has asked only 7 have been marked as answered or an abysmal 2.9%.

What does this tell me?

He has figured out it is 4 times easier to generate reputation points by posting questions then by posting answers. And asking a question requires only a minimum of superficial knowledge about a topic quickly gained from a quick read of an SEP topic or Wikipedia page.

Further more, he has no sincere interest in getting an answer to a question. The goal appears to be a combination of reputation point generation and the establishment of a platform for opinion based discussions. Since the questions stay unanswered they are recycled through the "Top Questions" queue to find more points and new discussions.

He asks (on average) 24 questions per month. Nearly a question a day but lately that number has jumped to 4 or 5 per day. This level of activity makes his questions the most likely to be seen by new users thus making him a defacto representative of this site.

He isn't qualified for that type of responsibility.

I think he shouldn't be allowed to ask any new questions until he goes through each of his 240 questions and marks an appropriate answer.

Also I believe the practice of awarding reputation points for questions should be removed. We aren't school children who need a gold star for a good question.

Comment: Your evaluation of the larger situation has some merit, but this doesn't answer the actual question that was asked.

Comment: @ChrisSunami Good point.  It was meant as a supplement to Phillip's answer.

Comment: I'd add, a good supplement at that.