Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes - Moderator Feedback
Given there has been a good deal of impassioned back and forth over the last couple months, and with the loss of Kristian Berry, a long-time 22k-reputed contributor (who has ventured out into the wilderness with his substack), and after meager, but inspired 8-person feedback from yesterday's post including the newest of participatory contrarians, I hereby ask for any objections from our democratically elected moderators for life for realizing JonathanZ's proposal for imitating MathSE's mechanism for tracking and handling additional debate and discussion on VTC.
I will given put my money where my mouth is by shaping a meta post of the form "Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes - Volume Q%n%20%yy%" without objection and begin populating.
See also: Should there be a "reopen/undelete suggestions" thread on meta?

@JonathanZ Conducting brief sentiment analysis on your last comment from the last post, I encourage you to produce 1.21 gigawatts of rhetorical persuasion should the moderators to whom courtesy has been extended on your suggestion waver.

I don't particularly object, but in my view we don't have the volume of posts where we need a specific thread for this. In particular my concern is: new user comes in, gets q closed, makes a meta post asking about it. Are we really going to say "please don't ask here, please write an answer to xyz question"?

@JD - It might be that I spent too much time as a consultant, but I don't have a position as to whether or not we should be doing reopen requests on meta - all I care about is that if people decide to do it that we do it the best way we can (which I think the math.se model is). So let the people debate, and then I'll help get that done.

@Kaia - Well, that is exactly what happens on math.se. But I think you've nailed the critical criterion: do we have enough volume to warrant the overhead? I feel like there has recently been a big uptick in the number of reopen requests, quite a few being made by a moderator even. It's hard (for me) to tell if this just a twitch, or a presaging of the new normal.

I'm not sure what problem this is meant to solve (don't fix what aint broke). Currently reopen requests are posted as questions (which you can tag with [meta-tag:closed-questions], or maybe [meta-tag:reopen-request]). Why doesn't that work for you? If you want to see questions that need to be reopened, you can just check new questions with that tag. If you want to avoid seeing requests already fulfilled, you can post an answer saying "This has been reopened" and accept it, or close the question, and then search for questions with the tag that are still open and don't have an accepted answer.

I get prompted with an icon when I visit philosophy.stackexchange.com and there are new questions on Meta. If there are new answers on Meta, I don't get prompted. So, be aware that answers in a reopening thread are less visible to me than new questions.

@causative -Can't you "follow" a given question and get notifications when they get new answers? I don't know all the details of how it works, but I could swear I've seen people discuss it.

@causative Can mods pin posts to the top of the feed?

This might be somewhat of an XY problem. The issue you're trying to solve is getting closed questions reopened as quickly as possible, whereas the underlying issue is too much disagreement about what should and shouldn't be closed. Most posts here are simply "let's reopen this specific question" rather than trying to come to agreement/consensus on criteria for closure, which one can then refer people to if a specific question is closed or getting close votes. But maybe the (unresolvable?) issue is that closure criteria is too subjective.

@NotThatGuy Collecting data in a single thread might help identify underlying patterns, including problematic users and the determination of the actual criteria being used for closure. Perhaps by having a thread, instead of fragmented one-off transactions, some consistency can be fostered. $0.02


"come to agreement/consensus on criteria for closure, which one can then refer people to if a specific question is closed or getting close votes" -> to prevent that question from getting closed, to get it reopened faster possibly without the need for a Meta post and/or to get others to conform to that consensus going forward (so there are fewer objectionable closures).


What about answer-deletes like this one

@NotThatGuy Tnx for xy-problem. We need a diagnosis before administering medicine

@Rushi: If you're talking about my answer, I deleted it because others had express the same ideas just as well, and I have no huge attachment to my words just because they are my words. I don't see any other deletion there, but it's possible I Ion't yet have sufficient rep on this board to be able to see it.

@keshlam Not you specifically. Rather the general view that this one problem alone is the problem. Proposals like this — I'm sure well-meaning — strike me aa incomplete diagnosis followed by ineffective prescription

To expand on my last comment, I seem to recall much of the same conflict about what's acceptable happening on Workplace some time ago, and on Interpersonal some time before that (about answers, not questions). In both cases, there were Meta Q&As where consensus was established or where moderators dictated site policy. I wouldn't know if that worked more broadly, because I left not long after that, because it was a clear signal that my moderation attempts and answers weren't welcome there. As it stands on this site now, I have no clue whether most people agree or disagree with recent closures.

Okay..here's a harsh counter argument.
I no longer believe that this site is able to fulfill its mission statement of providing answers to a majority of questions posted on this site. Most questions are simply a seed for discussion that lead to no definitive answers.
Is this Philosophy? Of course it is but its not the mission statement for this site.
In my opinion, the best action this site can take is a limit on the number of questions that a user can ask per week.
I vote for 3 per week. That will drastically reduce the question load faced by moderators. There are a number of users who ask 1 or more questions per day. That's hogging the sites resources.
I've addressed this issue before with a user who has been banned for life:
https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5549/67687
Another option is to raise the number of reputation points required to VTC. Let's leave that to the most "trusted" members of this site: 10k or higher. This would be even stronger if the 10k were based on points from answers to questions only. Additionally a minimum membership time should be imposed. A user who has only been here 60 days doesn't have enough site experience to VTC but may acquire the right number of reputation points.
Or just dump the vote to close. Currently, it's creating more problems than solutions


1 per day is a (D)DOS attack.  After all the 'servers' here are not GHz chips but the wetware in heads


Site rules allow for 6/day.  I consider that excessive.  I like the 3/week, and would even prefer 1/week.

"Most questions are simply a seed for discussion that lead to no definitive answers." I can't actually prove it, but that's been my best guess as to the motivation of the flood posters - they want to set the agenda for what is discussed here. One of their recent posts prefaced a link with "to ground the discussion here...", which is very far from "how do I get an answer?".

They've also taken to doing minor re-tagging on old questions that are on similar subjects to their recent post, so the first five questions on the front page are all on their subject. Heck, using other people's resources is what turns a DOS attack into a DOS attack. I'm sure it probably doesn't actually break any site rules, but it strikes me as very inconsiderate.

@Rushi - I think you and I disagree on a lot, but you get a solid "heck yeah!" from me for pointing out that it's people's attention, time, and energy that are the limited resources we shouldn't be wasting.

I wouldn't be all that opposed to limiting the number of questions per user. But I don't support all this business about getting rid of voting to close.

@JonathanZ You n I agree?! Time to throw a party? .
More seriously if we can stay within the island(s) of agreement then maybe we can reclaim more land from the so-to-say sea of disagreement and hopefully come to some consensus. So we seem to agree:  while I am personally not needing a rate-limit for users, I'm ok  considering that option beyond some threshold of general/public annoyance. Are you conversely prepared to also consider controls/limits on VTCs??

@Dcleve (Your Comment)  I'm fine between 1 and 3 per week. Note: I was saying something like this before (almost) anyone else

@Syed - There is a very strong guideline against "naming and shaming" other users, so most people end up saying "user who does XYZ". I agree that it can get a bit silly, but at least it tries to keep the focus on what's being done, as opposed to who is doing it.

@JonathanZ Referring to a specific user in every way except name - I might say that's following the "letter rather than the spirit" of not "naming and shaming", but even that's putting it very generously. They are clearly referring to a specific person ("this member"). Some degree of that is unavoidable when the front page is often dominated by questions from 1-2 users. But if that's the issue, then focus just on that, rather than bringing up their other behaviour. And "like a 3 year old" is just inappropriate.

@NotThatGuy. I've deleted the comment. The 3 year old reference was inappropriate.

I very much agree with this post.

Response to Comment
NotThatGuy

I'm not sure what problem this is meant to solve (don't fix what aint broke). Currently reopen requests are posted as questions (which you can tag with closed-questions, or maybe reopen-request). Why doesn't that work for you? If you want to see questions that need to be reopened, you can just check new questions with that tag. If you want to avoid seeing requests already fulfilled, you can post an answer saying "This has been reopened" and accept it, or close the question, and then search for questions with the tag that are still open and don't have an accepted answer.

I don't see it as a bugfix. I see it as a prototype of enhancement. I know there is a lot of discontent around the VTC mechanism, and it seems that MathSE has a potential feature we don't have. Why wouldn't we try it? It's not like we even have to roll back a branch from a repo. We just let the effort die. If it catches on, so be it, and if not so be it.
More importantly, it's an evidence-based approach to content moderation which serves the dual purposes of creating a mechanism to organize, and a mechanism to record. Nobody in this room would seem to be able to tell me much if I were to ask for a thorough accounting of closures. In fact, all concerns and criticisms are essentially loaded with questions because no one has the data to answer those moderation-centric questions at a glance.
Lastly, there have been some grumbling about new users who come on and spam the feed with minor variations on a theme. Some users have come and gone, but seemed to rely on pure LLM responses, and other's look like bots, sort of maybe. An additional artifact might help to identify patterns or provide quick summaries to those who don't work at their desk and check the site compulsively.

"there is a lot of discontent around the VTC mechanism" - is that going to be fixed by moving reopen requests to an isolated space with significantly reduced visibility? "no one has the data" - I'm not sure how moving reopen requests from questions to answers would help much with that (except that you can see a list with each whole request, instead of just the title and first 2 lines). Do you know about [data.se] - there's lots of data for you.

@NotThatGuy -- I agree that an answers thread on VTC will get less visibility than an explicit question on a VTC, and agree that will likely decrease our overturn rate on inappropriate VTC.  It looks to me like the main benefit is the strictly enforced "no hostility, no personalizing" that was also a feature of the MathSE answers suite.  I noticed that a particular mod was regularly getting overruled on that set of  answers, and it was done with no conflict and no drama.  The no-drama is a big advantage, but I fear the lower visibility would be an even bigger disadvantage.

Response to comment:
Kaia

I don't particularly object, but in my view we don't have the volume of posts where we need a specific thread for this. In particular my concern is: new user comes in, gets q closed, makes a meta post asking about it. Are we really going to say "please don't ask here, please write an answer to xyz question"?

Given Kristen Berry's departure which seems to have been around the VTC mechanism, it seems to me that the chaotic way in which posts are closed and reopened is part of the frustration. An orderly system for addressing complaints, keeping records, and facilitating discussion might actually increase the quality of posts by allowing more closure since there's not haphazard way of dealing with wrong closure.
Do we have the volume? What is the appropriate volume? Are we going to do or say x? These are all rather empirical questions. Empirical questions are best solved by experimentation, data collection, analysis, and provisional revision. There's no harm in trying it, and if it falls on its face, then nothing is loss, and a lesson is learned.

Adding my two cents. I think the solution is in human touch (moderation) and not in technical features/tricks. We don't need new 'meta' features to institute certain rules.
Just throw it in as an example:
Rule#...  Moderators can apply a 1-week suspension for those who cast more than 2 'close' votes a week without leaving a reasonable explanation for this vote.

For a short period of time, it will put extra load on moderators, but it will quickly quench these mad vigilantes' thirst.
